# Validation in AKKA.NET

Tags: akka.net

I have an actor called **OrderActor** which is the order being created for a customer. I have a validation rule that says *If the Product is a computer, allow only one item*. This rule should be applied whenever the OrderActor receives a message to add a product.

My question is about the Validation. Should I have a new actor called **OrderValidatorActor** and this needs to have the **OrderActor** as the parent actor? In this case, the flow of the events should be The **OrderActor** sends a message to the **OrderValidatorActor** which sends a response back to the **OrderActor** after validation.

Please guide on how to handle validation?

Comment: Why can't you validate this rule directly in **OrderActor**?

Comment: Validation is normally a business rule. It can be considered as a spec and can tested separately if it is a separate unit (separation Of Concern). That's why I'm considering the OrderValidatorActor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role/responsibility based object oriented programming principle apply in actor modeling also. The responsibility of validation is thus done in the **OrderValidatorActor**.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

1. Receive an *RequestAddItem* message in your **OrderActor**.
2. **OrderActor** sends the item details in a *ValidateOrderItem* message to **OrderValidatorActor**.
3. **OrderValidatorActor** sends either an *AddValidatedItem* or *DenyInvalidItem* message to the **OrderActor**.